# Regex interrogating a String NurseRoisteringProblem

Tags: java, regex

I am a third year student attempting to do my distinction on the Nurse Roistering Problem, i think this approach would help me in satisfying the soft constraints

The String below is a list of shifts for a given schedule

```
X = No Shift
E = Early
L = Late
D = day
N = Night
```

The Constraint i am attempting to check is `<MaxConsecutiveWorkingDays/>`

I am working in Java and attempting to find the following with regex.

Given the following  String  XXNNEXNDNNLXNNEXXLEXDXXXLNE I would like to find the count of how many times XNNEX occurs
.

Comment: And why would you need regex for that? `indexOf` method from String class can also accept position from where it should start searching, so each time you find what you want start searching after that place.

Comment: The question is ambiguous for a general string. Consider string "XNNEXNNEX". Do you expect the count to be 1 or 2?

Comment: Consider string "XNNEXNNEX" i would consider that to be 2 Thank You again

Comment: Loud, uproarious nurses?

Comment: Loud, uproarious nurses? I dont understand??

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comments ("XNNEXNNEX" = 2), String.split won't work for you. You can either use regex or String.indexOf. Both would be similar logically. I'm giving an example for regex:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestRegex {

  static final String test = "you test string";
  static final String PATTERN = "XNNEX";

  public final static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while(matcher.find(index)) {
        ++count;
        // this will reset the matching start point one char back
        // Note: this only works for "XXNEX". Please adjust the "step-back" based on
        // your actual pattern string. 
        index = matcher.end() - 1; 
    }
    System.out.println("count=" + count);
  }
}
```

Using `String.indexOf()` would be very similar: you need to reset your starting point after every match. But `String.indexOf()` cannot do regex matching.

Answer (score 1):

A better way use `String#indexOf()` method

```
String s="XXNNEXNDNNLXNNEXXLEXDXXXLNE";
int count=0;
int fromIndex=-1;
while ((fromIndex=s.indexOf("XNNEX",fromIndex+1))!=-1) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println(count); // 2
```

Comment: +1 for `indexOf` version. `Pattern`/`Matcher` version will not get correct result for input `XNNEXNNEX` because it doesn't let reusing same characters in separate matches (you would need look-behind to solve it), but if I ware you I would probably just remove this part from my answer (only `indexOf` seems enough/preferable here).

Comment: @Pshemo yes we have to avoid regex as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can split it based on the string that you want to match, and count the number of elements, and subtract 1 (the `+ "."` is to avoid empty end strings, which don't get included in the array).

```
String str = "XXNNEXNDNNLXNNEXXLEXDXXXLNE";
int numMatches = (str + ".").split("XNNEX").length - 1;
```

It works like this:

```
Initial string:
  XXNNEXNDNNLXNNEXXLEXDXXXLNE
Array after split:
 {X,    NDNNL,    XLEXDXXXLNE}
Length = 3
Number of "XNNEX"s removed = 3 - 1 = 2
```

EDIT: This will fail to work on strings such as XNNEXNNEX, where there are 2 overlapping matches.

Comment: Will fail in two cases (1) if `XNNEX` will be at end of string (because of trailing of empty strings in result array) (2) if characters can be part of few matches (`bob` exists two times in `bobob`)

Comment: Good point. I didn't see the comment on XNNEXNNEX being counted as 2. (end of string fixed by appending character)

Comment: Actually appending character can also mess things up because you can't be sure that this will not create another possible match. Better option would be using `split` with negative value as its [`limit` argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-).

Comment: The character I added (a period) could not be part of a match.

Comment: In this case yes, I was talking more about general solution.

Answer (score 0):

This could also work:

```
String str1 = "XXNNEXNDNNLXNNEXXLEXDXXXLNE";
String str2 = "XXNEX";
int count = (str1.Length-((str1.Replace(str2,"").Length))/str2.Length;
System.out.println(count);
```